# Automatically invite a specific person to every Outlook meeting

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, calendar

I use Outlook 2013 at work.  I use outlook.com for my personal stuff.  I also cannot have mobile phones at work, and I cannot access my work e-mail from my personal devices.

Currently, whenever I create an event on my calendar, I invite my outlook.com email to the meeting, so it shows up on my phone and my work computer.  This way, I know what appointments I have, even if I'm not in the office.

Is there any way to set up Outlook to automatically invite my outlook.com email to EVERY event I create?

Please note: I cannot use any fancy smancy software or anything.  My organization is pretty locked down.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Quick Step](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Automate-common-or-repetitive-tasks-with-Quick-Steps-a9caf57e-0eb0-4b48-9141-a9904da0aaf9?CorrelationId=1cdf1d85-eda4-4522-b400-fab9f07446f2&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) feature to create a meeting template.

[image]

1. Click ***Create New***
2. ***Name*** it what you wish
3. Click the ***Choose an action*** drop down
4. Scroll down to and select ***New Meeting***
5. In the ***To:*** box add your email address
6. Click ***Finish***

This new Quick Step now appears in the ribbon. Simply click it once to create a new meeting with your email already populated.

Comment: I'll check this out when I get to work!

Comment: This does work.  Is there any way to make this the default when I create a meeting using the standard controls?

Comment: Considering your statement "*My organization is pretty locked down*", I thought this to be the least invasive solution. I will look to see what it will take to modify the default.

Comment: If Outlook supports it, then I can do it.  If it involves a 3rd party tool, I cannot.

Answer (score 2):

For meeting invites coming into your inbox from other people, you can set up a rule that triggeres when a meeting invite comes to your inbox and have it forwarded to your outlook.com account. This does not solve the problem you mention all the way, but between the CharlieRB's method and this one, you should cover most of your event woes.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two simple steps to save a meeting form and make it your default. *NOTE: I'm using Outlook 2010, so things may look a little different.*

**First, you need to modify the meeting form and save it.**

1. Open a new meeting
2. Click the `Developer` tab (*if you don't have this, see source 1 below*)
3. Choose `Design this form` on the Developer ribbon
4. Type your email address in the `To` block
5. Click `Publish this form` on the ribbon and save in the `Calendar` folder as the name you wish
6. Close the open meeting form but don't save the meeting

**Second, set the default template for the meetings.**

1. Switch to Calendar view
2. `Right` click on the calendar in the folder pane on the left
3. Choose `Properties`
4. On the `General` tab, towards the middle, is `When posting to this
   folder, use:` drop down
5. Choose your form from this list
6. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>

Test verify it, click `New Meeting`. It should now open with your email address already populated.

[Source 1](http://www.slipstick.com/developer/tips-customizing-outlook-appointment-forms/)
[Source 2](http://www.slipstick.com/developer/how-to-apply-a-new-default-form-to-an-outlook-folder/)

Answer (score 1):

If your Outlook 2013 is hosted by Office 365 (Exchange Online), you can publish your Calendar. Your Outlook.com can possibly subscribe to it. The changes are not real-time and you may receive read-only updates once a day.

Comment: It's not hosted by O365.