# Is it possible to duplicate all calendar appointments to a central calendar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2013, calendar, exchange-2013

We use Exchange 2013 + Outlook 2013.

Currently, all of our users have their own separate calendar in which they plan appointments.

Due to the amount of employees, we would like to create a central calendar and make it so whenever a user plans an appointment in their own calendar this appointment gets duplicated/copied/synchronized to the central calendar.

This way our reception will only need to check one calendar to know which appointments to expect.

Does anyone know whether this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box its not possible to copy over appointments into another calendar. This is also not so easy as if you copy an element you might break stuff like (who is the owner, what is happing if the entry is canceled / rescheduled, need to calculate timezones, ... )

So you have the following options:

1. You could setup a taskuser (called e.g. Backoffice Calendar) and every user in your company need to invite that taskuser when inviting somebody via an calendar entry. This isn´t an automated solution, but via that way the reception has only one calendar to check. But your users needs to make sure that they include that in there invitations, so I really would go for option 2:
2. Why didn´t you come up with a "Room Ressource" which is handled by the reception? If there is then a meeting taking place the reception need to check and control the room resource mailbox. You users then need to include the room in there "invitations" and can also reserve the room. Your users can also see if the room is free or already booked and then need to choose another free slot. The reception can then approve the reservations making sure that VIPs are getting there time frame. On top of that the reception can then plan to handle the rooms, cook coffee put glasses in the room and such stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your response BastianW. I would like to automate the whole process. I cannot expect my users to add a specific room resource, or invite a taskuser for every appointment they make. One can dream but I highly doubt all users are capable of upholding such a system.

Comment: I see. You might wish to combine the room approach above with an adjusted and changed Form (see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/874655/automatically-invite-a-specific-person-to-every-outlook-meeting)). However this also might cause some issues so a propper training for your users would be the best I assume. Additional the approach above will also work via ActiveSync the change in the form not.  [Oh and please accept this answer here or at least upvote it if helpfull for you]

Comment: Hey BastianW, Maybe you're right about the proper training. I'm not sure whether it'll be upheld but I'll throw it in the group for discussion. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think that a training would be the best option here. I mean a resource mailbox is such a big useful feature that once the users understand that I´m very sure they will pick that up on there own (as they can check itself if a room is free when they book a meeting for example).

Comment: Just as an idea (not tested yet). You might also come up with a fancy script using New-MailboxSearch (running every x min) and then store the results in a 2nd mailbox (your shared combined calendar). But I personally think this isn´t error free and required a lot of work to implement that so that it is working as expected.